# PHP - Create instance of class (array param)

Tags: php, reflection, instance

For now, I'm creating an instance like this:

```
function newInstance($clazz, $parameters = []) {

    // Do other stuff before

    if(!is_array($parameters)) {
        $parameters = [$parameters];
    }

    // Do other stuff before

    return (new ReflectionClass($clazz))->newInstanceArgs($parameters)
}
```

The problem is:

Using an array as a single parameter, interprets it as an array of parameters instead of a single one. I also thought about using "func_get_args" or adding a third optional parameter which defines if there's an array as parameter or the given array contains all parameters, but I don't like that.

For example:

```
newInstance('clazzname', ['my', 'array']);

// should interpreted as:

function __construct($firstString, $secondString$) {}

// and sometimes as (depends on the class):

function __construct($myArray) {}
```

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use [variable-length arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) to handle this:

```
function newInstance($clazz, ...$parameters) {
    // Do other stuff before

    return (new ReflectionClass($clazz))->newInstanceArgs($parameters);
}

newInstance('clazzname', 'my', 'array');
// new clazzname('my', 'array');

newInstance('clazzname', ['my', 'array']);
// new clazzname(['my', 'array']);
```

Comment: Fantastic idea! Didn't know this exists in PHP, I only remembered in Java. Thanks!